# best linux based OS to use with Thinclients?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am using NComputing x550's(thin client) with  a single hp proliant ML110 with ubuntu 11 installed on it. Once the number os users reaches 3, the perfomaces gows down like the system responds slow.   What is the best linux distro that will work good with Firefox,phpedit or some other editor based on ubuntu or redhat.

Comment: You're likely starving the host for resources (probably RAM or HD). Also, as others have pointed out, the X550 is not a Thin Client solution, it's a multi-head desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Normally I'd say that any of them would work fine since the way we use a thin client is to connect to a terminal server somewhere. However, it sounds like the thin client will contain the entire OS. In that case, take a look at Puppy Linux and Damn Small Linux. Both are extremely small distros and have applications for most uses in that small footprint. You could also take a look at Linux From Scratch, this allows you to roll your own distro.

Source(s):

http://www.puppylinux.org/
http://damnsmalllinux.org/
http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/

Comment: no i am not going to do any modification in the thinclient. I just want a distro which supports firefox and still slow so that my single box can support more users.

Answer (score 0):

X550's are ([AFAICS](http://www.ncomputing.com/docs/guides/en/guide_X550_X350.pdf)) **not** thin clients - indeed they don't even appear to be terminals, it looks like they are additional displays/keyboards on the host system. As such they only create load on the server, they'll never take load off the server.

Using Xterminals will help with the performance - but if the access is via HTTP, then it makes a lot more sense to run a browser client at the terminal.

"no i am not going to do any modification in the thinclient" (Satya) - then there's nothing much you can do to improve performance. Using Chrome instead of Firefox may help, along with the usual tuning, but its not the right way to solve the problem.

Really, go buy some cheap PCs. You should be able to find new, low-spec machines with no storage for under $100 (US).

Comment: purchasing low-spec boxes will not solve my issue. we are trying to reduce the power consumption to 20% or the regular usage with this setup.

Comment: The X550 are just additional keyboards/displays/etc for the "server" (usually a beefy desktop, though apparently not in this case). It's probably simple resource contention, especially considering he's using the ultra cheap ML110.

Comment: @Satya: If you switch all the computers off you'll save a lot of power. Sometimes you need to take a less blinkered approach. Have a look at guru plug, tranquil, gumstix.....